# Android, Make constraint layout behave like button in talkback

Tags: android, button, accessibility, android-constraintlayout, talkback

I have a following constraint layout:

`sampleconstraint.xml`

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:text="magic text">
    </TextView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and a class:

```
class Sampleconstraint @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    val attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    val defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    val binding = SampleconstraintBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true)
}
```

I want it to behave like a button in talkback (because it will have more Views inside in real app) like title subtitle etc.

I've tried to set a role to it:

```
binding.constraintLayoutAsButton.isClickable = true
binding.constraintLayoutAsButton.setAccessibilityRoleToButton()

internal fun View.setAccessibilityRoleToButton() {
    ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(this, object : AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        override fun onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(
            host: View,
            info: AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat
        ) {
            super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info)
            info.className = Button::class.java.name
        }
    })
}
```

It is now read as "Button, magic text, double tap to activate"

When I use normal button it reads text first:
"Magic text, Button, double tap to activate"

How do I make constraint layout to behave like a button in this case?